# Magento SOAP Fault "Invalid XML"

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, soap-api-v2

When i try to access

> https://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/

It always gives

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP- 
   ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
       <faultcode>Sender</faultcode>
       <faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
     </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

but

> https://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

gives right output. Don't know .Please help me out. Thanks in Advance.